# How to make P. load and MAPE under the FCRBM, AFC-STLF, Bi-Level, MI-ANN. In the coding of the given table?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{Smart Grid}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Analysis}
\label{tab:M_CPE}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{10}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Proposed and existing forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{3-10}
{Hours} &
{Target} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCRBM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{AFC-STLF} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bi-level} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{MI-ANN} \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}
 & {P.load(kW)} & {MAPE(\%)} 
 & {P.load (kW)} & {MAPE(\%)} 
 & {P.load (kW)} & {MAPE(\%)} 
 & {P.load(kW)} & {MAPE(\%)} \\
\midrule

1 & 1.10 & 1.03 & 0.78 & 2.13 & 1.46 & 0.78 & 2.27 & 1.30 & 0.73 \\
2 & 1.44 & 0.95 & 0.67 & 2.17 & 1.47 & 0.60 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.48  \\
\midrule
{Avg.} & 1.10 & 1.03& 0.79 & 2.20 & 1.25 & 0.65 &  2.10 & 1.35 & 0.60  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing a `&` in front of the first `{P.load (kW)}`.

Comment: Respected @ egreg, I have used and in front of {P.load (kW)}. But the problem is that {P.load (kW)} comes under the target column and I want to make {P.load(kW)} & {MAPE(\%)} Under FCRBM, AFC-STLF, Bi-Level, MI-ANN. Please help me in this regard. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: There must be *two* `&` tokens before the first `{P.load (kW)}`: one is there, you're missing another one.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two empty cells in the table's third row, but you're inserting just one.

Also the columns are ten, rather than eleven as you set.

I changed `(kW)` into the proper `(\si{\kilo\watt})`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Analysis}
\label{tab:M_CPE}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{9}{S[table-format=1.2]} % 9, not 10
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Proposed and existing forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{3-10}
{Hours} &
{Target} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{FCRBM} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{AFC-STLF} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bi-level} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{MI-ANN} \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}
 &                                                        % <---- this was missing
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)} 
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)} 
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)} 
 & {P.load (\si{\kilo\watt})} & {MAPE (\%)} \\
\midrule

1 & 1.10 & 1.03 & 0.78 & 2.13 & 1.46 & 0.78 & 2.27 & 1.30 & 0.73 \\
2 & 1.44 & 0.95 & 0.67 & 2.17 & 1.47 & 0.60 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.48  \\
\midrule
{Avg.} & 1.10 & 1.03& 0.79 & 2.20 & 1.25 & 0.65 &  2.10 & 1.35 & 0.60  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

By the way, `\hyphenation{Smart Grid}` does nothing at all: the two words don't get hyphenated anyway.

You should consider removing the first row and incorporating it into the caption.

[image]